¿Cómo generar un PDF desde un procedure object en Genexus SD 16 v11?
Deseo hacer desde el layout del procedure un PDF, he intentado poner en las reglas output_file("Report.pdf","PDF); con las propiedades de Call protocol = HTTP, Connectivity Support = Offline y Report Output = Only to file, pero no se genera ni se abre ningun archivo.
Intenté abrirlo con interop(&fileUrl) pero se cierra la aplicación.

La aplicación es online u offline. Entenderas que si es online, el pdf se va a generar en el servidor y que tendras que descargar de una url.
Saludos.

Es offline la aplicación, acabo de darme cuenta que no es la v11 sino es version anterior, investigué y solo a partir de la v11 se puede hacer eso, existe otra manera de generar un PDF?
